# Checkbox preselection is not working on EntityType Field (ManyToMany)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

My Symfony version is 2.7.3. I have `Vehicle` entity, which has `WorldCountry` field (unidirectional ManyToMany):

```
/**
 * Vehicle
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicle")
 */
class Vehicle
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\WorldCountry", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="vehicle_country_join",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicle_id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $countries;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ...
        $this->countries = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

I have form for vehicle creation/editing:

```
/**
 * Class VehicleType
 * @package AppBundle\Form\Vehicle
 */
class VehicleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('countries', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:WorldCountry',
                'choices' => $this->worldManager->getCountriesByRegionIds([1]),
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('submit', 'submit');

        // ...
    }
}
```

Vehicle creation works fine, for example as result I have: 
[image]

**The problem** is that on vehicle editing page countries are not preselected (“Kyrgyzstan” in that example), when “choices” option is used:

[image]

But without it countries are preselected:

[image]

`$this->worldManager->getCountriesByRegionIds([1])` - returns array of `WorldCountry` from repository.

**UPDATE**
Accidentally  I have updated Symfony up to v2.8.7 - now it works as expected :)

*P.S. Please let me know if more information is required.*

Comment: Seems like you solved it. What's the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that I need to use `choices` option (I have clarified my question).

Comment: If you want to preselect choices in your entity type, you need to use the `data` option. You need to pass the array of `WorldCountry[]` that you want to be preselected.

Comment: I think `data` is not suitable in that case. Because creating a form I pass `Vehicle` object with regions, countries etc (`$this>createForm('app_vehicle', $vehicle)`),  so preselection must be automatic. See my question update.